# Get program to catch signal after wake from suspend?

Tags: suspend, power-management

I'm running a program (specifically [oscam](http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/)) that interfaces with a serial reader on a USB port. However, the tty device file that the USB device gets assigned to differs and, in particular, changes when the system wakes up from suspend.

I've created a udev rule so as to assign a consistent tty device symlink to the serial reader. This worked out fine, and I can now always access it under the same name. This allowed me to include the symlinked name rather than the actual device name in the config file, so that I did not have to change it every other re-plug.

However, the program seems to resolve this to symlink the actual device tty upon loading its configurations. This means that, as long as the program is running, it will not re-resolve the alias when trying to access the device.

Now here's my issue; when I wake my computer from suspend, the program *is still running* and thus does *not* resolve the *now changed* symlink. It works fine when I then kill off the program and start it back up.

A possible solution would of course be to include this killing and restarting of the program in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`, but this feels hacky, and I would like to share my fix back into the upstream.

My question is thus; is there some kind of signal that is fired when my system **wakes from suspend**, and can I catch that signal? I would then get the program to re-resolve the link specified in the configuration file.

Comment: What about using `RUN` action within udev rule? so when ever the link is made the script will run (restart program...)

Comment: That is already better than my sleep.d solution I suppose, but still requires a restart-script. I'd much prefer to solve it at the source (i.e. get the program to re-resolve the configs).